# SSD in read only mode after power failure

Tags: ssd

I have a **SSD NVME 2 TB** and after a power failure in entire neighborhood my SSD show issues. It has 2 partitions: NTFS (390.62 GiB) and BTRFS (1.44 TiB). I have checked system in both Windows and Linux, some files were restored, some fixed. BTRFS checked has no errors detected.

After 1 day it says input/output error. Can't mount for too long: it mounts but data disappears and need to umount and mount again. It's impossible to delete partition or format. It is in **read only mode**.

Info from smartctl seems bad.

```
$ smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.1.30-1-lts] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Netac NVMe SSD 2TB
Serial Number:                      AA8226200343
Firmware Version:                   2.1.0.1S
PCI Vendor ID:                      0x1f40
PCI Vendor Subsystem ID:            0x5216
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x123456
Total NVM Capacity:                 2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      0
NVMe Version:                       1.4
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Fri Aug  4 19:03:41 2023 UTC
Firmware Updates (0x0e):            7 Slots
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x0014):     DS_Mngmt Sav/Sel_Feat
Log Page Attributes (0x02):         Cmd_Eff_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         32 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     110 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     255 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     3.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        5       5
 1 +     2.80W       -        -    1  1  1  1       50     100
 2 +     2.70W       -        -    2  2  2  2       50     200
 3 -   0.0500W       -        -    3  3  3  3     2000    5000
 4 -   0.0030W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000   25000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         3

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
- media has been placed in read only mode

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x08
Temperature:                        54 Celsius
Available Spare:                    15%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    1%
Data Units Read:                    50,930,466 [26.0 TB]
Data Units Written:                 27,868,293 [14.2 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 269,580,731
Host Write Commands:                199,129,081
Controller Busy Time:               25
Power Cycles:                       564
Power On Hours:                     2,161
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   9
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    511
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               55 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               0 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 3:               43 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 64 entries)
No Errors Logged

free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**Is it possible to recover this SSD?**

Comment: Do you mean that the disk has entered into read-only mode and you can't even reformat it? I'm missing in your output the section of "Vendor Specific SMART Attributes", perhaps it will show up with `smartctl -A`.

Comment: Yes, it's in read only mode and i can't reformat it. Vendor specific Smart is there, just scroll down the code block. Thank you for your time.

Comment: SSD's can fail "gracefully" into read-only mode, to preserve data when its death is imminent. 1. Boot from an external device, e.g., USB, and image the SSD, or at least salvage data and personalization. 2. Now that data is safe, try utilities such as https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/remove-write-protection-ssd.html from EaseUS to salvage the drive. Good luck, and let us know what you did, if it works, as an answer.

Comment: No. Back up data ASAP and replace the drive. It's read-only at firmware level, this has nothing to do with partition level write protection. If anything then it should be some utility provided by the support of the SSD manufacturer.

Comment: I have trashed the SSD. Read only mode is not working very well: the SDD umount itself after a few seconds. Fortunately i was able to recover all important files. I will buy a NOBREAK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your disk is heavily damaged. I refer to these lines from the smartctl
output:

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
- media has been placed in read only mode
[...]
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Your disk has failed and the firmware as a last-ditch effort has placed
it in read-only state. The disk has failed so seriously that it managed
to cause a crash in smartctl (which is very rare).

Save all the data on the disk for which you don't have backups.
Backups from before the disk failed might be more trustworthy than
the data you can copy from the disk.

Then replace the disk with a new one.